# Icon within FloatingActionButton is in the bottom right corner, can't seem to center it

Tags: android, android-layout

My issue is that my floating action button's icon is in the corner when I want it in the center.

[image: Here is how it looks like:]

Here is the XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rv_select">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/create_routine_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/cardAccent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:elevation="10dp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the vector I am using(I just created one using android studio):

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:autoMirrored="true" 
    android:height="24dp"
    android:tint="#FFFFFF" 
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0" 
    android:width="24dp">
    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M19,13h-6v6h- 
    2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
</vector>
```

I've spent hours on this issue and would really appreciate some help!

EDIT: I figured it out... I was missing the right style

```
 <item name="floatingActionButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton</item>
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly...

Comment: I have tried your code and it seems fine, nothing wrong with it. Show me your full  xml file.

Comment: @ChiragRaval Edited post

Comment: Tried, works fine. Nothing wrong with this.

Comment: @AndrewP Just for a test: remove android:autoMirrored="true" from the vector

Comment: @mTak no change

Comment: Are you getting this issue after run app in device or emulator or in Preview of design layout?

Comment: Is the picture you‘re using correct and centered?

Comment: @MikeKng He is using the vector drawable for it

Comment: @ChiragRaval I am getting the issue both on a physical device and emulator, here is how it looks in preview: https://i.imgur.com/k0yO7qG.png

Comment: Please check this image, i have used your code only. https://ibb.co/kfWy6K

Comment: @ChiragRaval which version of the dependencies are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
  android:layout_margin="16dp"
  app:fabSize="normal"
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
  tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat"
  />

//vectore file 
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#ffffffff"
    android:pathData="M19,13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
</vector>
```

[image]

Comment: When I use app:srcCompat the button disappears altogether

Comment: i've edited the code snippet , please try with it. It's work for me

Comment: Which version of the dependencies are you using?

Comment: i'm using implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

Answer (score -1):

Use this code

1> implement this dependence

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'

2>

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/vec_file" />
```